# Dynamic loading content in Adobe Muse using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, audio-player, muse

I like using Adobe Muse due to its simplicity in Design, feels more like a graphic designing tool than web programming software.

I have a home page where I would like to place a music player. The home page leads to 2 other info pages. I'd like to make the player continue playing the music without refreshing itself when the user goes to the other pages.

Is this possible in Adobe Muse? Muse already utilizes jQuery and has an HTML *insert option* for custom code (like YouTube embedding). How to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not so much with Muse as with browsers. When you navigate to a new page they will stop playing any media on the page that is closing. So, you will need to keep a window open with your music player to ensure continuity. You could do this by using JavaScript to open a small popup window showing a page that contains just your music player. The window.open function will do this for you. However, your site visitors may dislike having a popup window open and anyway it may not open if they have a popup blocker enabled.

By the way, it is generally considered a bad idea to play music automatically on a website. Your visitors may already be listening to their own music so they won't want to hear yours at the same time. Many people just find it annoying, particularly when it is unexpected. If you music is relevant to your site and necessary (e.g. it's the website for a band) then add a music player widget and let the visitor press play before making any noise.